# Execute all commands in current folder sequentially

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

Assuming I have a bunch of `sqlcmd` commands in .cmd files, order alphabetically e.g.:

1. 01.setup.cmd
2. 02.version1.cmd
3. 03.version2.cmd
4. 04.version3.cmd

how could one **sequentially** execute these in correct order with another .cmd file?

Comment: Do you need to use a cmd file or can you use a shell script to do it for you?

Comment: What environment? Windows? *nix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b *.cmd') do call "%a"
```

This just loops over the result of `dir /b *.cmd` calling each in turn.

explanation from the docs:

> FOR /F processing of a text file consists of reading the file, one
>   line of text at a time and then breaking the line up into individual
>   items of data called 'tokens'. The DO command is then executed with
>   the parameter(s) set to the token(s) found.

So my command says:

- `"tokens=*"`  don't give me individual tokens, give me the whole line as one hit
- `%a` - name the line variable %a (note: it'll needs to be escaped as %%a if you're putting it in a batch file
- `('dir /b *.cmd')` This is the input that it'll loop over. A bare directory listing for all .cmd files
- then what I want it to do. Call the command %a.

If I didn't add the tokens bit it would work fine until you find a space in the file names.

Comment: I just tried this on a DOS command line - I like it - Can you edit/explain the answer a bit more. I'm more familiar with *nix shell scripting, less so with dos batch file scripting. Thanks

Comment: @Tsar - When you place it in a batch file use %%a instead of %a otherwise this should work fine.

Comment: @fiprojects - I've added a bit of an explanation.

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi!